# NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

When I update the user's profile I keep getting the error **NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id**. I have tried to fix it by setting the argument commit to False `form.save(commit =False)` then performing `form.save()`. My question is how can I update my profile and the user field of the Profile model is populated automatically by the currently authenticated user.

Here is my code...

**users/views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy("users:login"))
def profile(request,slug):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit = False)
        form.cleaned_data["user"] = request.user
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Profile updated successfully!")
        return redirect("users:profile", kwargs="profile")
    
else:
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username = slug)
    form = ProfileUpdateForm()

context = {"profile":profile,"form":form}

return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)
```

**users/models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank = True)
    image = models.ImageField(default = "default.jpg", upload_to = "profile_pics")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank = True)
    url = models.URLField(blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s profile"
```

**users/signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**users/forms.py**

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ["user"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad design in your profile view. If it ment to be only for editing request.user profile it should look like:

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy("users:login"))
def profile(request):
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit = False)
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Profile updated successfully!")
        return redirect("users:profile", kwargs="profile")
    
else:
    
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile)

context = {"profile":profile,"form":form}

return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)
```